# (solved)IO exception The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I'm trying to delete a line from a txt file with my program, but the program has the text file open so I can't. What do I do?

```
 private void btnDeleteTransaction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string line = null;
            string delete = txtDeleteTransId.Text;

            using (reader = new StreamReader(txtFilePath.Text))
            {
               try { 
                using (writer = new StreamWriter(txtFilePath.Text, true))
                {
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (String.Compare(line + "|", delete) == 0)
                            continue;

                        writer.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txtMessages.Text = "exception deleting transaction: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        }
```

Figured it out below.

Comment: What does "deleting a line from a txt file" mean to you?  You'll need to a) read all the text before the line, b) read the line, & c) read all the text after the line.  You need to glue the stuff from steps a) and c) together.  The easiest way to do this is to read from your file, & write to a 2nd file.  When you finish, delete the 1st file and rename the other one to have the same name as the first (you may also want to play file attributes games as well).  If you want to read and write to the same file, you'll need to open it for both read and write, and do some rather complicated juggling.

Comment: Text files are not random access.  That's why programmers prefer databases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm dumb and was trying to write from the reader which you can't do. Here is my working code if anyone is as new as me.

````
    private void btnDeleteTransaction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> records = new List<string>();
            found = false;
            using (reader = new StreamReader(txtFilePath.Text))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    record = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (record.StartsWith(txtDeleteTransId.Text + "|"))
                    {
                        found = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        records.Add(record);
                    }

                }
                if (!found)
                {
                    txtMessages.Text = "Record ID was not found";
                    return;
                }
            }
                try
                {
                    using (writer = new StreamWriter(txtFilePath.Text, false))
                    {
                        foreach (var item in records)
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(item);
                        }
                    }
                    txtMessages.Text = "Record deleted";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    txtMessages.Text = "exception deleting record: " + ex.Message;
                }

            }
    ```
````